# what is the difference between accumulate and cumulate?

Tags: word-usage

I find that these two words can be used to express to collect or gather. what is the difference between them? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's online definition:

> Did You Know? Cumulate and its far more common relative "accumulate"
>   both come from the Latin word cumulare, meaning "to heap up."
>   "Cumulare," in turn, comes from cumulus, meaning "mass." ("Cumulus"
>   functions as an English word in its own right as well. It can mean
>   "heap" or "accumulation," or it can refer to a kind of dense puffy
>   cloud with a flat base and rounded outlines.) "Cumulate" and
>   "accumulate" overlap in meaning, but you're likely to find "cumulate"
>   mostly in technical contexts. The word's related adjective,
>   "cumulative," however, is used more widely.

Beyond that, it can be said that **accumulate** is used about 30 times more frequently than **cumulate**, according to Google's Ngram Viewer.

On the other hand, the adjective **cumulative** is far more common than **accumulative** (again, see Google's Ngram viewer), so that in ordinary speech, snow **accumulates**, but **cumulative** totals are measured.